# Password reset flow for "Classic" accounts

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The docs state:

> This self-service password reset flow applies to local accounts in Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

How can I have a password reset functionality if my users are located in a legacy user store. (I'm using a REST Technical Profile to connect those)

If there is no built-in functionality for this kind of accounts, can I at least add a link to the sign-in form that will send the user to our legacy password reset page?

To clarify: by legacy/classic user store I mean a service that you can all over REST to validate credentials. Not another OIDC identity provider.

Comment: Federation is normally the way to go but this may also be an option? - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-different-identity-repository-for-authentication-using-azure-ad-b2c-e662bf17e072

Comment: @rbrayb I'm not connecting to another OIDC identity provider, just a REST service

Answer (score 2):

You could have B2C present its password reset pages, and right at the end, instead of writing the password to the B2C directory, call a REST API to write it to your legacy IdP/user database.

The only way B2C can hand off and hand back from an external provider, is by using federation, eg SAML/OpenId connect. If you want to go down this path, have the user enter their email in B2C UI, and once you determine that it is a legacy account, redirect them to the IdP using OpenId/SAML.

Comment: The first part is interesting.. Do you have any code samples for that? I'm not sure how I would implement this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment.

Replace this in the "PasswordReset" user journey:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials"   TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

with the call to your REST API.